# vdirsyncer sync error

Tags: sync, calendar

Have started to get this error.
I'm syncing between calendar on server (one.com) and client Kubuntu 20.04

The problem is always with a public holiday item.

```
Syncing khal_sync/calendar
error: Unknown error occured for khal_sync/calendar: /calendars/users/bill-
lancaster@brackenwood.one/calendar/ca6af7456b0088abad9a69f9f620f5ac-2021-01-01-
NewYearsDay@gov.uk.ics
```

Any ideas would be welcome since `vdirsyncer` has been working flawlessly for a very long time now.

Answer (score 0):

Although there was no item either on the server or on the client, exporting the server calendar enabled me to examine the entire conten of each ics item.
A event was found that somehow had the offending reference (ca6...etc) in it's URL field.  Removing this item from both server and client results in a clean sync.